# max malloc size lower than expected

Tags: c++, memory-management

Here is a simple program which checks maximum malloc size:

```
#include <iostream>

std::size_t maxDataSize = 2097152000; //2000mb

void MallocTest(void*& ptr)
{
    while (1)
    {
        ptr = malloc(maxDataSize);

        if (ptr)
        {
            std::cout << "Malloc success: " << maxDataSize << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        maxDataSize -= 1024;

        if (maxDataSize <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }           
    }
}

int main()
{
    void* ptr = nullptr;
    MallocTest(ptr);
    if (ptr)
    {
        free(ptr);
    }
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I use Windows 10 x64 and Visual Studio 2017. When I run that program I get successfully malloc call for ~1300mb. The program is built using 32bit architecture (release mode) so theoretically a memory limit equals 2GB. Is there anything which causes a memory fragmentation ? Why I can't allocate more than ~1300mb ?

Comment: The system itself probably takes up quite a bit of memory.

Comment: *Everything* causes memory fragmentation.

Comment: Ok, by-value pointer passing is fixed - the C tag can't apply anymore though, right?

Comment: How do you know the heap is 2GB?

Comment: This is system specific, implementation specific and operating system specific. On Linux, use [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html). Without a lot more details (what OS, what compiler, what compilation option, what `libc` version, what other programs are running, ....), your question is unclear

Comment: With MSVC, you can only get about 2MB memory *in total* from static and dynamic allocation between them.

Comment: @MaxLanghof, you're right.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, a function has been refactored.

Comment: @Irbis that's much better

Comment: I meant 2 GB of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: The bulk of this answer was written before OP indicated what OS they're using. The concepts are still valid but the specifics may be different.

You said your OS is 32-bit, and indeed a *good* 32-bit implementation will have a hard limit of 2 GB, because objects larger than `PTRDIFF_MAX` have lots of subtle problems, both easily causing undefined behavior when you use them, and triggering compiler bugs dealing with pointer arithmetic. However you've hit some lower limiting factor.

On Linux, the virtual address space limit for 32-bit processes is 3 GB on most archs, 2 GB on some, and full 4 GB for some when a 32-bit process is running on a 64-bit kernel. However, in this space, a number of things are already mapped that *fragment* the address space and limit the length of any contiguous range. This includes the program itself, and if it's dynamic-linked, the dynamic linker and any shared libraries it's using.

If your program is not built as PIE (position-independent executable), the default base address for it on Linux/x86 is 128 MB. This splits off the first 128 MB of the address space as not usable with the contiguous upper part. Libraries are typically loaded just below the upper address space limit, splitting off some from that end, but probably not too much. ASLR (address space layout randomization) *may* move them down a bit, but mainline kernels don't do that by too much to avoid heavily fragmenting the already very-limited address space. Some kernels patched for additional hardening may randomize much more.

Ultimately, large contiguous allocations (greater than half a GB or so, maybe even less than that) are not reliably available on 32-bit systems. If you need them you probably need to be using a 64-bit system. But a better choice might be figuring out alternate data structures that don't require a contigous allocation or even that can work with data that doesn't fit in memory.

Comment: @Irbis: Ah. I didn't guess right. I'll leave this since it might be relevant to others with similar question, or suggesting the *concepts* that might be behind what you're hitting, but I don't know the specific mechanisms of how it fails on 32-bit Windows

Comment: I use 64-bit OS, the program is built using 32-bit architecture.

Comment: @Irbis all those explanations are also more or less valid for Windows. If you are asking specifically for Windws, you should add the [WINDOWS] tag